# Add JavaScript reference from code behind (C#)

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

Is it possible to add javascript reference dynamically from code behind aspx.cs?

Like this:

```
private void AddScriptReference(string path)
{
   //Add reference to <head></head>
}
```

Should result in a script reference being added to the head of the page, like this:

```
<html>
   <head>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="path-to-script.js"></script>
   </head>
</html>
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [`ASP.NET Ajax ScriptManager`](http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/Section/Using-the-ASP-NET-AJAX-ScriptManager.id-305492.html) to do so.

Add it to your masterpage, and use [`ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptInclude`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360649.aspx) from your codebehind.

Comment: Thank you, I should have known this :P

Answer (score 27):

Bit late but thought I'd post an answer to this in case anybody else needs it. This solution negates the need for a ScriptManager.

Basically, it's just a case of creating a control and then adding to the head. Here's the code.

```
LiteralControl javascriptRef = new LiteralControl("<script type='text/javascript' src='path_to_script.js'></script>");

Page.Header.Controls.Add(javascriptRef);
```

Comment: I appreciate the non-ScriptManager solution.  It allows loading script links into the header programatically (e.g. I'm using it in a masterpage to manage the .js weight on site pages).

Answer (score 8):

For those who want to know the syntax, here it is:

Master Page:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager" EnablePageMethods="true" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
```

Code behind:

```
ScriptReference sr = new ScriptReference("path-to-js.js");
ScriptManager sm = (ScriptManager)this.Master.FindControl("ScriptManager");
sm.Scripts.Add(sr);
```

Or:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptInclude(this.Page, GetType(), "UniqueID", "path-to-js.js");
```

But none of these solutions actually add the script to the head of the page..