# Highlighting Text in a Textbox on a Web Page Using C#

Tags: c#, textbox

Is there anyway to highlight the initial text in a textbox on a web page using C#?  I know how to do this on windows forms but I can't find any example of how to do it on a web page.

Any advice is appreciated.

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do it using C#. Websites are not like windows forms, but you can do it using Javascript. 
You should check out [jQuery](http://jquery.com/).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with [javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Input.select).

```
document.getElementById('textbox-id').select();
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to use javascript.  Example:

```
document.getElementById('test').focus();
document.getElementById('test').select();
```

You can do this from the codebehind if you like and register the script from there.

That has been discussed in this question: [Add JavaScript reference from code behind (C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701534/add-javascript-reference-from-code-behind-c)

Answer (score 0):

You need to do it client side, so you should use javascript.  If you are using jquery you can do a:

```
$("#myTextBox").select();
```

Answer (score 0):

Answers given before should meet your needs. But if you want to use server side c# coding you can use these lines in your `Page_Load` function:

```
    TextBox1.Text = "This Is the initial text";

    TextBox1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;
```

This will create the illusion of highlighting the initial text.